# Not able to do maven release with jasypt encryption

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-release-plugin, jasypt

I've a Springboot project handled by maven that contains some secrets encrypted with Jasypt. When I'm running the `mvn deploy` I'm passing the jasypt password as:

```
mvn -B clean deploy -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}
```

And it is able to run test cases and deploy the jar file to repository. But when I'm doing the same with `mvn release` the jasypt password is not properly set.

```
mvn -B clean release:prepare release:perform -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}
```

Or

```
mvn -B release:prepare -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}
```

For both these cases, I'm getting following error while running the test cases.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Encryption configuration property missing: jasypt.encryptor.password

The plugin configuration I'm using is:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How should I set jasypt password while running the maven release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the issue solved using following command. Apparently maven release plugin takes configuration parameters in a different way.

```
mvn -B clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Djasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this link](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/11) which gives more details about the issue.

Basically it states that

> Once you enable jasypt-spring-boot the password property is required
>   as specified in the documentation

They have suggested multiple solutions. One of them being:

Add `jasypt.encryptor.password=dummy` to your springboot properties file.

And another (if running from command line), run your jar with

`-Djasypt.encryptor.password=*******************`

Comment: The issue was with how maven release plugin takes the configuration parameters. I've posted an answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij,
[image]

Using
`-Djasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}` as Project argument should resolve your issue.

If it doesnot help then try
`--jasypt.encryptor.password=${jasypt_password}`.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
***Manu***